# Make a 2D out of 1D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following 1D numpy array:

```
li = array([ 0.002,  0.003,  0.005,  0.009])

li.shape
(4L,)
```

I would like to make a 2D numpy array (li_2d) with shape of (4L,5L) that looks like this:

```
li_2d = array([[  0.002,   0.002,   0.002,  0.002,  0.002],
               [  0.003,   0.003,   0.003,  0.003,  0.003],
               [  0.005,   0.005,   0.005,  0.005,  0.005]
               [  0.009,   0.009,   0.009,  0.009,  0.009]])
```

Is there some numpy function to do that?
Thank you

Comment: I think there's probably a duplicate somewhere but I'm not sure that's the right one (e.g. the duplicate will show how to use `tile` or `repeat`).

Comment: Yep, I was too quick. Here's the correct one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550130/cloning-row-or-column-vectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the desired shape using [`numpy.tile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
li = np.array([ 0.002,  0.003,  0.005,  0.009])
np.tile(li.reshape(4, 1), (1, 5))

array([[ 0.002,  0.002,  0.002,  0.002,  0.002],
       [ 0.003,  0.003,  0.003,  0.003,  0.003],
       [ 0.005,  0.005,  0.005,  0.005,  0.005],
       [ 0.009,  0.009,  0.009,  0.009,  0.009]])
```

Comment: Thank you, to me that seems the easiest solution.

Comment: @diegus You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `np.pad`. First, reshape your array to a shape of `(4,1)`, then pad 4 columns on the edge:

```
In [18]: np.pad(li.reshape(4,1),((0,0),(0,4)),mode='edge')
Out[18]: 
array([[ 0.002,  0.002,  0.002,  0.002,  0.002],
       [ 0.003,  0.003,  0.003,  0.003,  0.003],
       [ 0.005,  0.005,  0.005,  0.005,  0.005],
       [ 0.009,  0.009,  0.009,  0.009,  0.009]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with `numpy.repeat`:

```
In [5]: np.repeat(li, 5).reshape(li.shape[0], 5)
Out[5]: 
array([[ 0.002,  0.002,  0.002,  0.002,  0.002],
       [ 0.003,  0.003,  0.003,  0.003,  0.003],
       [ 0.005,  0.005,  0.005,  0.005,  0.005],
       [ 0.009,  0.009,  0.009,  0.009,  0.009]])
```

You can get the transpose by either using `numpy.tile` or the transpose operator:

```
In [8]: np.tile(li, 5).reshape(5, li.shape[0])
Out[8]: 
array([[ 0.002,  0.003,  0.005,  0.009],
       [ 0.002,  0.003,  0.005,  0.009],
       [ 0.002,  0.003,  0.005,  0.009],
       [ 0.002,  0.003,  0.005,  0.009],
       [ 0.002,  0.003,  0.005,  0.009]])

In [9]: np.repeat(li, 5).reshape(li.shape[0], 5).T
Out[9]: 
array([[ 0.002,  0.003,  0.005,  0.009],
       [ 0.002,  0.003,  0.005,  0.009],
       [ 0.002,  0.003,  0.005,  0.009],
       [ 0.002,  0.003,  0.005,  0.009],
       [ 0.002,  0.003,  0.005,  0.009]])
```