# Add copies of a dimension in Python - numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, opencv3.0, dimensions

I have an image (numpy.ndarray) shaped like this:

```
In : print(img.shape)
Out : (240, 320, 1)

In : print(img) # The output it's simplified
Out:[[[121]
      [119]
      [118]
      ..., 
      [ 39]
      [ 43]
      [ 44]]
```

And I need to add copies to look like this:

```
shape (240, 320, 3) 
    [[[121   121   121]
      [119   119   119]
      [118   118   118]
      ..., 
      [ 39   39   39]
      [ 43   43   43]
      [ 44   44   44]]
```

Any tips on how to achieve that?

Comment: Look into tile/repeat for NumPy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1582742/2776376