# Repeating rows of matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a question that is related to this post: ["Cloning" row or column vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550130/cloning-row-or-column-vectors). I tried to work around the answers posted there, yet failed to apply them to my problem.

---

In my case, I'd like to "clone" each row row of a matrix by converting a matrix like

```
A = [1,2; 3, 4; 5, 6]
```

into the matrix

```
B = [1, 2
     1, 2
     3, 4
     3, 4
     5, 6
     5, 6]
```

by repeating each row of `A` a number of times.

---

So far, I was able to work with `repmat` for a single row like

```
A = [1, 2];
B = repmat(A, 2, 1)

>> B = [1, 2
        1, 2]
```

I was trying to build a loop using that formula, in order to obtain the matrix wanted. The loop looked like

```
T = 3; N = 2;
for t = 1:T
    for I = 1:N
      B = repmat(C, 21, 1)
    end
end
```

Has anyone an idea how to correctly write the loop, or a better way to do this?

Comment: `B = repmat(A,2,1)` does not give the result you wrote. If I understand right your question, you want something like `B=kron(A,[1;1])`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### `kron`

There are a few ways you can do this. The shortest way would be to use the [`kron`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) function as suggested by Adiel in the comments.

```
A = [1,2; 3, 4; 5, 6];
B = kron(A, [1;1]);
```

Note that the number of elements in the ones vector controls how many times each row is duplicated. For `n` times, use `kron(A, ones(n,1))`.

`kron` calculates the kronecker tensor product, which is not necessarily a *fast* process, nor is it intuitive to understand, but it does give the right result!

---

#### `reshape` and `repmat`

A more understandable process might involve a combination of `reshape` and `repmat`. The aim is to reshape the matrix into a row vector, repeat it the desired number of times, then reshape it again to regain the two-column matrix.

```
B = reshape(repmat(reshape(A, 1, []), 2, 1), [], 2);
```

Note that the `2` within the `repmat` function controls how many times each row is duplicated. For `n` times, use `reshape(repmat(reshape(A, 1, []), n, 1), [], 2)`.

---

#### Speed

A quick benchmark can be written:

```
% Setup, using a large A
A = rand(1e5, 2);
f = @() kron(A, [1;1]);
g = @() reshape(repmat(reshape(A, 1, []), 2, 1), [], 2);
% timing
timeit(f);
timeit(g);
```

Output:

- `kron` option: 
  0.0016622 secs
- `repmat`/`reshape` option: 
  0.0012831 secs

Extended benchmark over different sizes:

[image: benchmark]

**Summary**:

- the `reshape` option is quicker (~25%) for just duplicating the rows once each, so you should go for this option if you want to end up with 2 of each row for a large matrix.
- the `reshape` option appears to have complexity O(n) for the number of row repetitions. `kron` has some initial overhead, but is *much* quicker when you want many repetitions and hardly slows down because of them! Go for the `kron` method if you are doing more than a few repetitions.

Comment: Thank for explaining things that I'm lazy for... :) And, for the interesting benchmark!

Comment: Thanks so much to all of you! 
@Adiel: I got it to work in my code. Sorry for the misspecification earlier. You were of great help!
Wolfie: Your answer is of such great help, especially for a beginner like me! Thank you! 
... Unfortunatelly I cannot vote for your reply. Most probably, I have to earn this privilege first ;)

Comment: Accepting the answer is good enough for me @Joe, cheers! If you wanted to see the steps in the second method for learning, you can do each of the 3 operations individually. I just bundled them together because I was competing with a solution which took only a dozen characters!

Comment: @Adiel You may find my edit interesting, appears `kron` is pacey for lots of duplications.

Comment: Hey, interesting indeed. Thanks!