# Replace Nan in DataFrame based on value in Second DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Seems like there are many DF questions with conditions from another DF but I can't find any that do what I need.  Both dataframes are small samples.  They are each thousands of columns wide.  I have a DataFrame (df1) that looks like this

```
             IBM    BA      CAT     IBM EARN    BA EARN   CAT EARN
Date
1/22/2018   163.13  65.94   76.50     NaN        NaN       NaN
1/23/2018   163.17  65.94   76.51     NaN        NaN       NaN
1/24/2018   167.26  67.43   79.23     NaN        NaN       NaN
1/25/2018   166.28  67.77   80.57     NaN        NaN       NaN
1/26/2018   166.58  68.37   80.87     NaN        NaN       NaN
1/27/2018   166.77  68.87   81.07     NaN        NaN       NaN
1/28/2018   167.98  68.57   81.07     NaN        NaN       NaN
2/1/2018    167.98  68.77   81.59     NaN        NaN       NaN
2/2/2018    167.98  69.07   81.87     NaN        NaN       NaN
```

I have another dataframe (df2) with identical columns as the last three in df1 but with specific dates

```
    IBM EARN    BA EARN     CAT EARN
0   1/22/2018   2/1/2018    1/26/2018
1   10/19/2017  10/26/2017  10/25/2017
2   7/20/2017   7/27/2017   7/26/2017
3   4/20/2017   4/27/2017   4/26/2017
4   1/23/2017   1/26/2017   1/27/2017
5   10/19/2016  10/27/2016  10/26/2016
6   7/20/2016   7/28/2016   7/27/2016
```

I want to place a 1 in df1 where there is a corresponding date in df2.  So the (partial) result would look like this but would continue for all dates list in df2.

```
             IBM     BA     CAT     IBM EARN    BA EARN   CAT EARN
Date
1/22/2018   163.13  65.94   76.50    **1**       NaN       NaN
1/23/2018   163.17  65.94   76.51     NaN        NaN       NaN
1/24/2018   167.26  67.43   79.23     NaN        NaN       NaN
1/25/2018   166.28  67.77   80.57     NaN        NaN       NaN
1/26/2018   166.58  68.37   80.87     NaN        NaN        **1**
1/27/2018   166.77  68.87   81.07     NaN        NaN       NaN
1/28/2018   167.98  68.57   81.07     NaN        NaN       NaN
2/1/2018    167.98  68.77   81.59     NaN        **1**     NaN
2/2/2018    167.98  69.07   81.87     NaN        NaN       NaN
```

Please let me know if you can help with a solution

Comment: please post desired output not partial output

Comment: I dont have the entire output unfortunately because it is more than 1000 lines but df1 has daily dates (as the index) and stock prices and I want to put a 1 in each instance from df2 where there is a date.  So for IBM it would be 1/22/2018 (as shown) and then 10/19/17 then 7/20/17,etc.   Same for the other 2 columns with the dates

Comment: @JWestwood - I add also non loop solution, if you are interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each column of second `DaatFrame` check membership by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) and with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) replace values:

```
for col in df2.columns:
    df1[col] = np.where(df1.index.isin(df2[col]),1,np.nan)
print (df1)
              IBM     BA    CAT  IBM EARN  BA EARN  CAT EARN
Date                                                        
1/22/2018  163.13  65.94  76.50       1.0      NaN       NaN
1/23/2018  163.17  65.94  76.51       NaN      NaN       NaN
1/24/2018  167.26  67.43  79.23       NaN      NaN       NaN
1/25/2018  166.28  67.77  80.57       NaN      NaN       NaN
1/26/2018  166.58  68.37  80.87       NaN      NaN       1.0
1/27/2018  166.77  68.87  81.07       NaN      NaN       NaN
1/28/2018  167.98  68.57  81.07       NaN      NaN       NaN
2/1/2018   167.98  68.77  81.59       NaN      1.0       NaN
2/2/2018   167.98  69.07  81.87       NaN      NaN       NaN
```

EDIT:

Non loop solution with [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) by dictionary of list created by `df2` with cast boolean mask to integers:

```
#first create DataFrame by repeat index of df1
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/45118399
arr = np.broadcast_to(df1.index[:, None], (len(df1), len(df2.columns)))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=df2.columns, index=df1.index)

df3 = df3.isin(df2.to_dict('l')).astype(int)
print (df3)
           IBM EARN  BA EARN  CAT EARN
Date                                  
1/22/2018         1        0         0
1/23/2018         0        0         0
1/24/2018         0        0         0
1/25/2018         0        0         0
1/26/2018         0        0         1
1/27/2018         0        0         0
1/28/2018         0        0         0
2/1/2018          0        1         0
2/2/2018          0        0         0

df1 = df1.drop(df2.columns, 1).join(df3)
print (df1)
              IBM     BA    CAT  IBM EARN  BA EARN  CAT EARN
Date                                                        
1/22/2018  163.13  65.94  76.50         1        0         0
1/23/2018  163.17  65.94  76.51         0        0         0
1/24/2018  167.26  67.43  79.23         0        0         0
1/25/2018  166.28  67.77  80.57         0        0         0
1/26/2018  166.58  68.37  80.87         0        0         1
1/27/2018  166.77  68.87  81.07         0        0         0
1/28/2018  167.98  68.57  81.07         0        0         0
2/1/2018   167.98  68.77  81.59         0        1         0
2/2/2018   167.98  69.07  81.87         0        0         0
```

Comment: very nice solution without loops.

Comment: @shivsn - Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this as date is your index:

```
In [18]: df1['IBMEARN'] = np.where(df1.index.isin(df2.IBMEARN),1,0)

In [19]: df1['BAEARN'] = np.where(df1.index.isin(df2.BAEARN),1,0)

In [21]: df1['CATEARN'] = np.where(df1.index.isin(df2.CATEARN),1,0)
In [22]: df1
Out[22]: 
              IBM     BA    CAT  IBMEARN  BAEARN  CATEARN
DATE                                                     
1/22/2018  163.13  65.94  76.50        1       0        0
1/23/2018  163.17  65.94  76.51        0       0        0
1/24/2018  167.26  67.43  79.23        0       0        0
1/25/2018  166.28  67.77  80.57        0       0        0
1/26/2018  166.58  68.37  80.87        0       0        1
1/27/2018  166.77  68.87  81.07        0       0        0
1/28/2018  167.98  68.57  81.07        0       0        0
2/1/2018   167.98  68.77  81.59        0       1        0
2/2/2018   167.98  69.07  81.87        0       0        0
```

Comment: Yes that does work so it is correct but I have more than 3000 columns (stocks) so I guess I could loop through them and do it but was wondering if there was a more pythonic way to do all those columns rather than a loop.  let me know if you can think of anything.  ty

Comment: I see loop posted from @jezreal.  That seems simple enough.  I think both answer are correct.  I will mark as such if I can credit 2 answers

Comment: @JWestwood I think jezreal answer is better you should accept that.