# Numpy append multiple different np.arrays in one axis of existing np.array

Tags: python, numpy

I have

```
x = np.array([[1, 5], [2, 8]])
x.shape
```

The shape of x is (2,2)

How do I make new array y, that will contain 40 different arrays of the same shape x? The desired y array should be of dimension (40,2,2)

When I try y = np.expand_dims(x, axis=1) it gives me shape (2, 1, 2).
I don't understand how numpy append things in different axes...
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Cloning" row or column vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550130/cloning-row-or-column-vectors)

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher thanks for the replay, but I didn't mean a copy from this array, but rather appending different arrays of same shape x.

Comment: maby np.dstack will help?

Comment: @KrzysztofJurkiewicz: Just answered a minute ago :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wrote you want an array `y` of higher dimension, you can simply initialize an array of zeros as

```
y = np.zeros((40, x.shape[0],x.shape[1]))
print (y.shape)
# (40, 2, 2)
```

where you provide the size of the array `x`.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment below, here is the answer. You can use [dstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) where you provide the arrays to be stacked as a tuple `(x, z)` here and it stacks them along the third axis.

```
x = np.array([[1, 5], [2, 8]])  
z = np.array([[11, 55], [22, 88]]) 
y = np.dstack((x,z))
y.shape
# (2, 2, 2)
```

**EDIT 2**

To stack it in the front, you can use `swapaxes` an swap the first and the third axes.

```
y = np.dstack((x,z,x)).swapaxes(0,2)
y.shape
# (3, 2, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay but the thing is I have already 40 different arrays. But for the sake of simplicity lets say I have 2 different arrays x = np.array([[1, 5], [2, 8]]) and 
z = np.array([[11, 55], [22, 88]]) . Now I want hew array y of dimesion (2,2,2) that appended this two arrays in the 0 axis

Comment: that edit extends the array in its last dimension, see y = np.dstack((x,z,x))  # (2,2,3)

Comment: `y = np.stack((x, y, z))` is an alternative to the `dstack` with `swap`.  It takes an axis parameter to give even more control.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 5], [2, 8]])

y = np.asanyarray([x] * 40)

print(y.shape)
```

The output shape would be (40, 2, 2).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to concatenate multiple arrays together in a new dimension:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 5], [2, 8]])
y = np.array([[11, 55], [22, 88]])

z = np.array([x, y, x])
print(z.shape)  # (3, 2, 2)
```

Comment: Do you really need the `tolist()`?