# 2D of numpy arange

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tile

I want to build two 2d arrays

```py
a = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
     [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
     [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
     [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]

b = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

But i cannot use for loops. i know i can get an array using np.arange(5), but not sure how to turn that into the 2 2D arrays shown above.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you mean you cannot use for loops or do you mean it is a restriction?

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps and consider accepting it. Cheers

Comment: Ill be using it to create big arrays, so using two for loops will make things very slow

Comment: A better duplicate target: [“Cloning” row or column vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1550130/7851470)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Cloning" row or column vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550130/cloning-row-or-column-vectors)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) or [`numpy.meshgrid()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html):

```
np.mgrid[0:6, 0:6]
# array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#         [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
#         [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
#         [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
#         [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]],
# 
#        [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]])

np.meshgrid(np.arange(6), np.arange(6))
# [array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#         [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]),
#  array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#         [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
#         [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
#         [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
#         [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]])]
```

and simply unpack the result

```
a, b = np.mgrid[0:6, 0:6]
```

Answer (score 4):

**You just need `numpy.reshape` and `numpy.repeat`. Use this:**

```
import numpy as np

n_columns = 6
a = np.repeat(np.arange(6), n_columns) 
a = a.reshape(6,n_columns)

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]])

b = a.T

array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

This code will work for any `n_columns` value.

Answer (score 2):

There is also `np.indices`:

```
 I,J = np.indices((6,6))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `np.repeat`:

```
>>> x = np.arange(6).reshape(1,-1)
>>> y = np.repeat(x,6,axis=0)
>>> y
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
>>> z = y.T
>>> z
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0]])
```

Comment: What's with the downvote? Can anybody explain?

Comment: The dimensions are not the same as the OP. Also this looks identical to the above answer (before my edits) and posted 2 min later. Cheers

Comment: Misunderstanding -- I did not (myself) downvote. I just said why someone could downvote it.

Comment: And just for the record, initially my 3 lines would address exactly the OP. then I edited to post the results/outputs

Comment: It was not, your first post was: `import numpy as np; a = np.repeat(np.arange(6),5); a.reshape(6,5)`. So you did not address the `.T` aspect in the first go. However, I am not saying you copied mine, or you did not know the transpose. A misunderstanding it is. Regardless, your first attempt was an incomplete one by long stretch, so try not be [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite) unless you address all the issues, you can beautify with edits later, that's fine.