# Expanding a vector to a new size

Tags: python, arrays

Given a vector, for example

```
my_list=[1, 2, 3]
```

how to expand each entry to a new matrix (seen as a multidimensional list or, more likely, a numpy array)?

For example, in the case of matrix being a numpy array of size 2x2 matrix, the output,  expanded_my_list, would be:

```
 [[[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[2, 2], [2, 2]], [[3, 3], [3, 3]]]
```

or as a numpy array:

```
array([[[1, 1],
    [1, 1]],

   [[2, 2],
    [2, 2]],

   [[3, 3],
    [3, 3]]])
```

where expanded_my_list.shape is (3,2,2).

Comment: You second snippet is not valid python. Do you mean to write three nested lists?

Comment: _Given a vector, for example_ It's important to be precise, that's a plain Python list. _E.g. in the case of matrix.shape to be 2x2 matrix:_ Where does the `shape` attribute come from? What's _matrix_ ? Please clarify things.

Comment: Corrected, thanks.

Comment: _Expanding a vector to a new size
Ask Question_ ... _Given a vector, for example_ ... _how to expand each entry to a new matrix? E.g. in the case of matrix.shape to be 2x2 matrix:_ ?

Comment: I don't think the _or as a numpy array:_ makes sense here, since the previous sentence already implies that the "matrix" is a NumPy ndarray.

Comment: _my_list.shape is (3,2,2)._ It isn't, it's _AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'_.

Comment: Ultimately none of this matters, since this question is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550130/cloning-row-or-column-vectors.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
[[[e] * 2 for _ in range(2)]  for e in my_list]
```

output:

```
[[[1, 1], [1, 1]], [[2, 2], [2, 2]], [[3, 3], [3, 3]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution may be:

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    expanded[:, i] = my_list[i].expand_as(matrix[:, i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`numpy.tile()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html).
By creating additional axis via `np.newaxis` and repeating the elements  of the list along these axis you can create your wanted result:

```py
import numpy as np

lst = [1, 2, 3]
arr = np.array(lst)

arr2 = np.tile(arr[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis], reps=(1, 2, 2))
# Output:
# array([[[1, 1],
#         [1, 1]],
#        [[2, 2],
#         [2, 2]],
#        [[3, 3],
#         [3, 3]]])

lst2 = arr2.tolist()  # If a nested list is required
```

Or more general:

```py
arr = np.array([[1, 2],
                [3, 4]])

expanded_shape = (3, 4)

arr2 = np.tile(arr.reshape(arr.shape + (1,)*len(expanded_shape)), 
               reps=(1,)*arr.ndim + expanded_shape)
```

```
# Output, shape (2, 2, 3, 4)
# array([[[[1, 1, 1, 1],
#          [1, 1, 1, 1],
#          [1, 1, 1, 1]],
#         [[2, 2, 2, 2],
#          [2, 2, 2, 2],
#          [2, 2, 2, 2]]],
#        [[[3, 3, 3, 3],
#          [3, 3, 3, 3],
#          [3, 3, 3, 3]],
#         [[4, 4, 4, 4],
#          [4, 4, 4, 4],
#          [4, 4, 4, 4]]]])
```