# Assign 1d numpy ndarray into columns of a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assume `dst` is an ndarray with shape (5, N), and `ramp` is an ndarray with shape (5,).  (In this case, N = 2):

```
>>> dst = np.zeros((5, 2))
>>> dst
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]])
>>> ramp = np.linspace(1.0, 2.0, 5)
>>> ramp
array([1.  , 1.25, 1.5 , 1.75, 2.  ])
```

Now I'd like to copy ramp into the columns of dst, resulting in this:

```
>>> dst
array([[1., 1.],
       [1.25., 1.25.],
       [1.5., 1.5.],
       [1.75, 1.75],
       [2.0, 2.0]])
```

I didn't expect this to work, and it doesn't:

```
>>> dst[:] = ramp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5) into shape (5,2)
```

This works, but I'm certain there's a more "numpyesque" way to accomplish this:

```
>>> dst[:] = ramp.repeat(dst.shape[1]).reshape(dst.shape)
>>> dst
array([[1.  , 1.  ],
       [1.25, 1.25],
       [1.5 , 1.5 ],
       [1.75, 1.75],
       [2.  , 2.  ]])
```

Any ideas?

### note

Unlike ["Cloning" row or column vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550130/cloning-row-or-column-vectors), I want to assign `ramp` into `dst` (or even a subset of `dst`).  In addition, the solution given there uses a python array as the source, not an ndarray, and thus requires calls to .transpose, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Cloning" row or column vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550130/cloning-row-or-column-vectors)

Comment: The suggested post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550130/cloning-row-or-column-vectors) ends up being much more complex than the answer given below.  And it doesn't address copying into a vector.  I never would have discovered this "nump-ish" technique otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**: Use broadcasting:

As OP mentioned in the comment. Broadcasting works on assigment too

```
dst[:] = ramp[:,None]
```

---

**Method 2**: Use `column_stack`

```
N = dst.shape[1]
dst[:] = np.column_stack([ramp.tolist()]*N)

Out[479]:
array([[1.  , 1.  ],
       [1.25, 1.25],
       [1.5 , 1.5 ],
       [1.75, 1.75],
       [2.  , 2.  ]])
```

---

**Method 3**: use `np.tile`

```
N = dst.shape[1]
dst[:] = np.tile(ramp[:,None], (1,N))
```

Comment: Ah!  Thank you for the `ramp[:,None]` hint.  This is even easier (since broadcasting works in this case): `dst[:] = ramp[:,None]`.  (If you agree, feel free to update your answer!)

Comment: hah! totally forgot about broadcasting works on assignment too. I added it to the answer :)