# Create a numpy array with all rows identical

Tags: python, numpy

Given a vector `v`, I would like to create a 2D numpy array with all rows equal to `v`. What is the best way to do this? There must be a faster way to do this than to use for loops. There are functions like `fill`, `ones` and `zeros` for filling the entire array with one value, but what about filling each column with the same value, but different values for each column?

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550130/cloning-row-or-column-vectors

Comment: Do you really need to create such an array?  How are you going to use it?

Answer (score 5):

Broadcasting may be useful:

```
v = np.random.normal(size=(4, 1))
v * np.ones((4, 3))
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1.29471919,  1.29471919,  1.29471919],
   [ 0.26505351,  0.26505351,  0.26505351],
   [ 1.04885901,  1.04885901,  1.04885901],
   [-0.18587621, -0.18587621, -0.18587621]])
```

Comment: This involves unnecessary multiplication, though, right?

Comment: Yep, but broadcasting may be faster than  np.repeat

Answer (score 4):

Use `np.repeat`. For example:

```
v = np.random.normal(size=(4, 1))
np.repeat(v, 3, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1.7676415 ,  1.7676415 ,  1.7676415 ],
       [ 0.77139662,  0.77139662,  0.77139662],
       [ 1.34501879,  1.34501879,  1.34501879],
       [-1.3641335 , -1.3641335 , -1.3641335 ]])
```

---

UPDATE: I recommend you use the answer from @balezz (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65795639/5763165) due to speed improvements. If the number of repeats is large the broadcasting method is better:

```
import timeit
setup = "import numpy as np; v = np.random.normal(size=(1000, 1))"
repeat, multiply = [], []
for i in range(50):
    multiply.append(timeit.timeit(f'v * np.ones((v.shape[0], {i}))', setup=setup, number=10000))
    repeat.append(timeit.timeit(f'np.repeat(v, {i}, axis=1)', setup=setup, number=10000))
```

Gives the following:

[image]

The improvement of `multiply` over `repeat` persists in most cases when varying the size of the input vector as well:

```
import timeit
repeat, multiply = [], []
for i in [2, 5, 10, 50, 100, 1000, 10000]:
    setup = f"import numpy as np; v = np.random.normal(size=({i}, 1))"
    repeat.append(timeit.timeit(f'np.repeat(v, 50, axis=1)', setup=setup, number=10000))
    multiply.append(timeit.timeit(f'v * np.ones((v.shape[0], 50))', setup=setup, number=10000))
```

[image]

Comment: Asked identical rows, not columns ))

Comment: Right. Sorry (I read that the rows should be identical e.g. row0 == row1). Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
np.full(shape, fill_value)
```

Specify the shape of the 2D array and pass your vector as the fill value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .full()
Else you can first use empty() to make an empty array and then use fill() to fill it with a certain value

```
np.full((no_of_rows,no_of_cols),the_no_u_want_evry_cell_to_have)
```

Example for 3x4 array with value of 69

```
np.full((3,4),69)
```

it gives an array of :

```
   [[69,69,69,69]]
   [[69,69,69,69]]
   [[69,69,69,69]]
   [[69,69,69,69]]
```

Comment: The question was about replicating a vector, not a single value.