# Cloning row in numpy.tile

Tags: python, numpy

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1582742/13326667 has details on cloning row using numpy.tile.

```
>>> tile(array([1,2,3]), (3, 1))
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

What is the purpose of `(3,1)` here? Can someone explain what the `3` means and the `1` means?

Comment: The `reps` parameter is a bit complicated but fully documented [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html). So please explain what exactly is unclear after reading the docs.

Comment: @timgeb I don't know so mcuh what it means "promoted to be d-dimensional by prepending new axes"

Comment: Yeah that's gibberish if you're not familiar with numpy. It basically says that the function will add new axes as needed. Maybe you should play around with different `reps` and inspect the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`3` is the number of times he have to clone it horizontally

and `1` is the number of times he have to clone it vertically:

for example if you have:

```
import numpy as np

tile = np.tile(
np.array([
    [1,2,3], #<- row 1 here
    [1,2,3]  #<- row 2 here
]),(2,2)
)
print(tile)
```

you would get the array, cloned 2 times vertically and 2 times horizontally:

```
[[1 2 3 1 2 3]
 [1 2 3 1 2 3]
 [1 2 3 1 2 3]
 [1 2 3 1 2 3]]
```

Comment: It starts to get interesting when you pass more than two values. A complete answer should explain that, too.